# Why does the function not work properly in the python tkinter button?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I was trying to make a simple database app to view and search for example customers. I've got code with 3 functions and it works correctly when I call it bellow, but when I add a new window in tkinter and assign the main function to the button, then the search function doesn't work. I tried changing the function call in the button to `lambda:search()` but unfortunately the search function still does not work and displaying all records.

```py
menu = Tk()




def search():
    global trv, q, conn,k

    # Tworzenie kursora
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ksiazka.db')
    k = conn.cursor()
    wyszukaj = Tk()
    q = StringVar()

    def update_new(rows):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('ksiazka.db')
        trv.delete(*trv.get_children())
        for i in rows:
            trv.insert('', 'end', values=i)
            conn.commit()

    def sercz():
        conn = sqlite3.connect('ksiazka.db')
        q2 = q.get()
        query = "SELECT *, oid FROM pracownicy WHERE imie LIKE '%" + q2 + "%' OR nazwisko LIKE '%" + q2 + "'"
        k.execute(query)
        rows = k.fetchall()
        update_new(rows)
        conn.commit()


    wrapper1 = LabelFrame(wyszukaj,text="Pracownicy")
    wrapper2 = LabelFrame(wyszukaj,text="Wyszukaj Pracownika")

    wrapper1.pack(fill="both", expand="yes",padx=20,pady=10)
    wrapper2.pack(fill="both",expand="yes",padx=20,pady=10)

    trv = ttk.Treeview(wrapper1, columns=(1,2,3,4,5,6),show="headings",height="6")
    trv.pack()

    trv.heading(1,text="customerid")
    trv.heading(2, text="customerid")
    trv.heading(3, text="customerid")
    trv.heading(4, text="customerid")
    trv.heading(5, text="customerid")
    trv.heading(6, text="customerid")

    query = "SELECT *,oid FROM pracownicy"
    k.execute(query)
    rows = k.fetchall()
    update_new(rows)

    #search section
    lbl = Label(wrapper2,text="Search")
    lbl.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT,padx=10)
    ent = Entry(wrapper2,textvariable=q)
    ent.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT,padx=6)
    butter = Button(wrapper2,text="Search",command=sercz)
    butter.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT,padx=6)


    wyszukaj.title("MyAPP")
    wyszukaj.geometry("800x700")
    wyszukaj.mainloop()



search_btn1 = Button(menu,text="Wyszukaj pracownika",command=search)
search_btn1.grid(row=12,column=0)

menu.geometry("500x500")
menu.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `q2` is what you expect it to be? Have you verified that the query is returning the correct values? Are you aware that you shouldn't be creating more than one instance of `Tk`?

Comment: Text `doesn't work.` is the most useless information. Don't expect that will run code to see what is the problem (we even could run it because we don't have your database). Besides, code may work correctly on our computers - and we can't read in your mind. You have to put all details in question (not in comments)

Comment: maybe first use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: tkinter should have only one main window `Tk()` and other windows should be created with `Toplevel()`. And it should use only one `mainloop()`

Comment: Sorry I am an amateur at programming and it turned out that it was the second instance of Tk that was causing the problem in the application. Thanks for the reply as I have been wondering what is wrong for a long time. Is there any way to leave the main window so as not to create a new instance?

Comment: @furas Thanks a lot this is exactly what I meant :)

Comment: if you want to use only one window and have different content then you can put widgets in `Frame` and replace this `Frame` in window - `pack_forget()` to remove (without deleting from memory), and `pack()` to put it back.